# 4 column (sub)query search, get results from related table

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, left-join

Sorry for the strange title, but I have no idea how to put this in words. 
I think it's best to give an example, there are 4 columns I want to include in this query (using DB2);

```
employee    keyword    employee_keyword    keyword_linked
--------    -------    ----------------    --------------
firstname   value      employee_id         key_id1
lastname    ....       keyword_id          key_id2
...                    ....                ...
```

Pretty straightforward really, there's an employee having a many-to-many relation with keywords, joined together by `employee_keyword`. The `keyword_linked` table 'links' keywords with eachother, so that the keyword 'IT' can be 'linked' to the keyword 'java' for example. What I would want is when someone searches for the keyword 'java', thet get all employees having 'java' as keyword + all employees that have a keyword that links to 'java' (so in this case all employees having 'IT' as a keyword). And that's where i'm stuck...

I've tried numerous queries but i'm not really getting anywhere. My current query doesn't include the `keyword_linked` table;

```
select * from TABLE e 
left join TABLE.function f on (f.id = e.function_id) 
left join TABLE.employee_service es on (e.id = es.employee_id) 
left join TABLE.service s on (es.service_id = s.id) 
left join TABLE.employee_keyword ek on (e.id = ek.employee_id) 
left join TABLE.keyword k on (ek.keyword_id = k.id) 
left join TABLE.employee_keyword ek2 on (e.id = ek2.employee_id) 
left join TABLE.keyword k2 on (ek2.keyword_id = k2.id) 
left join TABLE.employee_service es2 on (e.id = es2.employee_id) 
left join TABLE.service s2 on (es2.service_id = s2.id)
and e.deleted is null
```

So this is my current query that needs to be expanded with the `keyword_linked` table. I think I have to use a subquery, where I ask all `key_id2`'s (in the`keyword_linked` table) of which the `key_id1` is `id` of the keyword entered by the user....I hope I'm not too confusing :-)

So maybe something like this;

```
select e.firstname, k.value from TABLE  e
left join  employee_keyword ek on e.id = ek.employee_id
left join keyword k on k.id = ek.keyword_id
left join keyword_linked kl on k.id = kl.key_id1
where k.id in (select kkl.key_id1 from TABLE.keyword_linked kkl)
```

But this isn't really it. If someone could help me, that would be highly appreciated! Also can you include an explanation in your answer, queries aren't really my strong point and i'm trying to understand what i'm doing wrong.

Thnx in advanced!

Comment: Hello! Are all the linked keywords linked explicitly? I mean, do you have to assume that if 'IT' is linked to 'java' and 'IT' is linked to 'SQL' then 'SQL' is linked to 'Java'? Or in this case you have an explicit link between 'SQL' and 'Java' (known as 'transitive closure')?

Comment: We have given that some thought and decided not to do this for several reasons. So 'SQL' is not linked to 'java' unless you explicitly say so (which in your example is not the case).

ps: don't you mean implicit?

Comment: No, I really mean explicit, I've just checked it again with my Ru-En dictionairy :) So you have to calculate the 'missing' links on the fly and work with them as well, correct?

Comment: Hmmm, well as I understand it; if I don't define a link between 'SQL' and 'java' anywhere, but if there would be a link between them because of other links, that would be called an implicit link. When you actually in code define a link between 'IT' and 'java' that would be called an explicit link. But anyway, I *do not* have to worry about any 'missing links' no. =)
The only links that matter in your example would be 'IT' -> 'java' and 'IT' -> 'SQL' and NOT 'SQL' -> 'java'. It would only matter if I in code define that there would be a link between those 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work only with explicitly interlinked keywords, the query should be as follows:

```
    select  emp.*
    from    employee emp
            join employee_keyword emp_kw ON emp_kw.employee_id = emp.id
    where   emp_kw.keyword_id in (        
        /*keyword iteslf*/
        select  id from keyword where value = 'java'
        union
        /*keywords linked with this word*/ 
        select  key_id2 key_id 
        from    kw_linked_x lnk
                join keyword kw on kw.id = key_id1
        where   kw.value = 'java'
        /*keywords this word is linked with*/       
        union
        select  key_id1 key_id 
        from    kw_linked_x lnk
                join keyword kw on kw.id = key_id2
        where   kw.value = 'java'
    )
```

But there's also a way to establish implicit linkage between the keywords, which should give you more value:

```
    with kw_linked_x  as (
        /* Ensure that key_id2 is greater than key_id1 */
        select  least(key_id1,key_id2) key_id1, 
                greatest(key_id1, key_id2) key_id2 
        from    keyword_linked
    )
    select  emp.*
    from    employee emp
            join employee_keyword emp_kw ON emp_kw.employee_id = emp.id
    where   emp_kw.keyword_id in
    (
        /* go down the 'tree'*/
        select  key_id1
        from    kw_linked_x lnk 
                join keyword kw on KW.id = lnk.key_id1
        start with kw.value='java' 
        connect by prior key_id2 = key_id1
        union 
        /* go up the tree */
        select  key_id1
        from    kw_linked_x lnk 
                join keyword kw on KW.id = lnk.key_id1
        start with kw.value='java' 
        connect by prior key_id1 = key_id2
    )
```

Hope this helps.

*PS: In both queries 'java' should be replaced with the keyword you are quering for.*

Comment: Seems do to the trick at first sight/test. Although I will test thoroughly after the weekend, but I think this is what I wanted. Thank you so much Dmitry! :-)